# My eyeballs won't move with my rig

Tags: rigging, armature, mixamo

ETA
I parented the eyeballs to the head bone and it worked! Mixamo had hidden the bones so I did not think that it would be viable to parent the eyeballs to a bone, but if you choose the "bone" option then a drop down menu appears that allows you to select a bone and now the eyes are moving with the figure. I'm just adding this so other people will see it if they encounter the same issue.

[image: EYEBALLS FIXED][image: eyeballs in place]

I made a character and uploaded it into Mixamo. Mixamo wouldn't take my textures so I redid the textures with the new rigged mesh and I replaced the eyeballs using the TinyNocky eyeballs (because those eyes are just awesome). So the rig and mesh are all participating together except for the eyeballs. When I join the eyeballs to the other parts of the mesh, the body or the hair or the sweater or anything, the eyeballs refuse to move along with the body. I have parented the eyeballs to the armature as an object and as an armature and neither work.

[image: screenshot showing parenting and eyeballs]

Comment: Join them to the rest of the body, select them in Edit mode and assign them to the same vertex group as the rest of the head?

Comment: Feel free to post the solution to your problem in the answer section below. You also can mark your answer as "accepted" with a green checkmark so other people who have the same problem will easily find it.